# Format date string to remove time in JAVA

Tags: java, string, date

Example, String value is:

```
15/08/2013 15:30 GMT+10:00
```

I want to format above string to `15/08/2013` (remove time part and only keep date) in Java.

How can I do this format?

Comment: Use `SimpleDateFormat` code - `DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm z");`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Remove time part and only keep date

```
String dateString= "15/08/2013 15:30 GMT+10:00";
String result  = dateString.split(" ")[0];
```

That gives you  `15/08/2013`

There is no need to formatter, I guess.

Comment: As i have only date string and does not have date variable. Also just want it to format to keep date part only. so, it would work. Thanks.

Comment: @Dhaval  Me also used date string only,Not Date object.Have a close look.

Comment: Simple, sir @SureshAtta

Answer (score 5):

## 2018

Since it's now 2018 and we have the date/time API in Java 8+ (and the [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/)), you could do something like...

```
String text = "15/08/2013 15:30 GMT+10:00";
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(text, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm z", Locale.ENGLISH));
System.out.println(ldt);

// In case you just want to do some "date" manipulation, without the time component
LocalDate ld = ldt.toLocalDate();
// Will produce "2013-08-15"
//String format = ldt.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE);
String format = ldt.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy"));
System.out.println(format);
```

## Original Answer

One approach would be to parse the `String` date to a `Date` object and then simply format as per your requirements

```
String text = "15/08/2013 15:30 GMT+10:00";
SimpleDateFormat inFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm z");
Date date = inFormat.parse(text);
System.out.println(date);

SimpleDateFormat outFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
String formatted = outFormat.format(date);
System.out.println(formatted);
```

This has the nice benefit of preserving the date/time information in the `Date` should you need it for other things ;)

See, [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for more details

Answer (score 1):

If this is nothing more than you have a string containing `15/08/2013 15:30 GMT+10:00` and you just want the date part, which is the first 10 characters of the string, I'd just take the first 10 characters; no need to parse and format it as a date:

```
String input = "15/08/2013 15:30 GMT+10:00";
String result = input.substring(0, 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the DateFormat class, 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

You should be able to parse in the date using a parser and then write out your desired format in another pattern

i.e. new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm z") for inbound

new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy") for your updated format

Answer (score 0):

Try using the SimpleDateFormat class: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html

Answer (score 0):

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
Date date = (Date) formatter.parse(dateStr);
```